# Alarm, even if application is shutdown

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, process, alarm

I have integrated a small to-do list in my WinForms application, where-in user can add tasks and set alarm for it. Is it possible to run timer (or alarm clock counter) in background, even if application is closed. I am using the `AlarmClass` written as answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493203/alarm-clock-application-in-net). The aim is only to show a MessageBox when the alarm time is reached and nothing else to do with the application. Also multiple alarm setting should be possible.

I am sorry if my question is not elaborated, coz I dont know wat other details I must include. But ready to reply your questions.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit: Any comments on this [link](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Creating-an-Alarm-Clock-in-the-System-Tray)?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure, but can't you create a Windows application which only shows up in the Systemtray. Add the required keys to the registry to make sure it will automatically start when windows starts.

Otherwise you can split it up into two separate applications;
- Windows Application to manage the alert
- Windows Service to do the check in the background

Comment: Hmm good idea to separate application in two parts. I have never created a service before, I will try to find some literature and samples on it. Thanks

Comment: Any comments on this [link](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Creating-an-Alarm-Clock-in-the-System-Tray) ?

Comment: That tutorial seems to be pretty easy. Of course it's a little bit too basic for your needs (i.e. multiple alarms) and you should definately store the alarms in a file/database. But its a good start!

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer**

No. If your application is shut down, there's no good way.

**Long answer**

Yes if you resort to clever hackery. You could:

- Run your app in the system tray / background when the 'X' button is clicked
- Run a scheduled task which launches your app in "alarm-checking" mode every N minutes
- Write a windows service which launches your app for alarm events

Comment: Thanks for input seed, I will dig more on these points and post queries if any.

Comment: Any comments on this [link](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Creating-an-Alarm-Clock-in-the-System-Tray)

Comment: @Niraj: The alarm clock app in your link is a good approach, and fits in well with Chris' first suggestion. It has a UI and shows how to park it in the system tray. Easier to implement than a Windows service (which doesn't have a UI).

Comment: @Niraj Looks good to me, however this approach does have its drawbacks. For example, you'll need to make sure the app is always running (auto-start). Furthermore if the user decides to kill it (on purpose or accidentally), no more alerts. I suppose you should probably leave that decision to the user anyway, so this seems like a good approach.