# Is there a better way to set an alarm clock than this?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to set a function to run at a specific time in a day in c#.
This code seems to work but I am not so confident about it. Is there any better way around this?

this is my code

```
String thetimeis = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
DateTime alarmtimeStart = Convert.ToDateTime("12:00:00");
DateTime alarmtimeStop = Convert.ToDateTime("12:02:00");

if (Convert.ToDateTime(thetimeis) > alarmtimeStart && Convert.ToDateTime(thetimeis) < alarmtimeStop)
{
  MessageBox.Show(thetimeis);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alarm clock application in .Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493203/alarm-clock-application-in-net).

Comment: the problem is not the alarm application here. but the management of string and datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am bit confused why you need so much conversion, is it not better the following?

```
if (DateTime.Now > alarmtimeStart && DateTime.Now < alarmtimeStop) 
{ 
  MessageBox.Show(thetimeis); 
}
```

Comment: because I need to set the time from a textbox manually each time

Comment: oh you meen the "String thetimeis = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
" is not needed ?

Comment: well its not working with datetime.now. I need to check the time directly not the date also.

Comment: its a win service i am trying to do, but I am testing the code in a console application

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for a more robust solution to scheduling jobs I'd recommend using [Quartz](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/). For trivial jobs, it's probably overkill, but I've found it easy to use and much easier than rolling my own solution.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's a better way - just compare hours, minutes and seconds individually.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime alarmtimeStart = Convert.ToDateTime("12:00:00");
DateTime alarmtimeStop = Convert.ToDateTime("12:02:00");

if (now.Hour >= alarmtimeStart.Hour && now.Minute >= alarmtimeStart.Minute && now.Second >= alarmtimeStart.Second && now.Hour <= alarmtimeStop.Hour && now.Minute <= alarmtimeStop.Minute && now.Second <= alarmtimeStop.Second)
{
    MessageBox.Show(thetimeis);
}
```

Comment: lol I wonder if we also put milliseconds, will the execution time of the "if checks" overtake the current time, will it ever enter the if statement :P. Thanx

Comment: @themhz: Unless you're running on an 8080, the `if` should only take a matter of nanoseconds :)

Comment: DateTimes support the `<` [operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.op_lessthan.aspx), so there is no need to compare them component-by-component.

Comment: @Douglas: That will compare the date as well. The point is that we're only looking to compare the time. But see BlueMonkMN's answer for the right way.

Comment: Yes, then `TimeOfDay`is better. If the date is never important, then [TimeSpan.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9.aspx) could be used instead of `Convert.ToDateTime`.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you directly compare the TimeOfDay properties of the dates?

**Edit:**

```
TimeSpan thetimeis = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
TimeSpan alarmtimeStart = new TimeSpan(12, 0, 0);
TimeSpan alarmtimeStop = new TimeSpan(12, 2, 0);

if (thetimeis >= alarmtimeStart && thetimeis < alarmtimeStop)
{
   MessageBox.Show(thetimeis);
}
```

Comment: can you demonstrate what your saying? I need to set manually the time of the alarm each time. And in some days it could change