# How do i check if a set time equals the system Time

Tags: c#, datetime, clock

I'm making a little alarm clock as a project to practice as I'm just a beginner.

I got 2 textboxes in which the user can put in the hours and minutes at which he wants the alarm to go off.

How do i check if the alarm time provided by the user is the same as the time on his system / pc?

Comment: You may see this thread for the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493203/alarm-clock-application-in-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
int hours = System.DateTime.Now.Hour;
int minutes = System.DateTime.Now.Minute;

if(Convert.Toint32(txtHours.Text) == hours && Convert.Toint32(txtMinutes.Text) == minutes)
{
  // same time 
}
else
{
  // time not same
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a litle sample to get you on your way

```
    int myMinute = 5;
    int myHour = 19;

    if (DateTime.Now.Minute == myMinute && DateTime.Now.Hour == myHour)
    { 
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

All above answers are helpful but you should make in practice to use TimeSpan for comparing date or time.

```
int hour=5;
int min=20;
int sec=0;
TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan(hour, min, sec);
TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
// see if start comes before end
if (time == now)
{
    //put your condition
}
```

Please see this url for more info.

[How to check if DateTime.Now is between two given DateTimes for time part only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12998739/how-to-check-if-datetime-now-is-between-two-given-datetimes-for-time-part-only)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Convert.ToInt32(tbHours.Text) == DateTime.Now.Hours 
&& Convert.ToInt32(tbMinutes.Text) == DateTime.Now.Minutes)
    {
        //set off alarm
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var current = DateTime.Now;
if (current.Hour == 9 && current.Minute == 0) {
    //It is 9:00 now
}
```