# How to check if DateTime.Now is between two given DateTimes for time part only?

Tags: c#

For my app I need to know if `Now()` is between two values.

The user can set a start- and an end-time so he will not disturbed by a notification (during the night for example).

So if have got two `TimePicker`s (start- and end-time) that the user can set.

Lets say the user sets `22:00` for the `StartTime` and `07:00` for the `EndTime` (this would cover the night).

How can I check if the `DateTime.Now` is between the selected Start and End time?

**EDIT:**
I only want this to work with the Hour and minutes part. So if the user sets the Start and End time this should work for every night.

Comment: I'm afraid that of the half-dozen answers, mine is the only answer that appears to work for your example times.

Comment: Could you elaborate why?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

First you need to convert everything to the same units (we'll use `TimeSpan`), then you need to see whether the start-end times cross midnight, and finally do your comparison based on the results of that check:

```
// convert everything to TimeSpan
TimeSpan start = new TimeSpan(22, 0, 0);
TimeSpan end = new TimeSpan(07, 0, 0);
TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
// see if start comes before end
if (start < end)
    return start <= now && now <= end;
// start is after end, so do the inverse comparison
return !(end < now && now < start);
```

Here's a function to do it for you:

```
bool TimeBetween(DateTime datetime, TimeSpan start, TimeSpan end)
{
    // convert datetime to a TimeSpan
    TimeSpan now = datetime.TimeOfDay;
    // see if start comes before end
    if (start < end)
        return start <= now && now <= end;
    // start is after end, so do the inverse comparison
    return !(end < now && now < start);
}
```

You would call it like:

```
bool silenceAlarm = TimeBetween(DateTime.Now, StartTime.Value, EndTime.Value);
```

Comment: Very nice.  Thanks Gabe.

Answer (score 10):

Since you are only gathering two times without dates, you need to figure out if the two times are from the same day or not. If you put the `StartTime`, `EndTime`, and `Now` into `TimeSpans`:

```
if (StartTime > EndTime) 
{
    // the range crosses midnight, do the comparisons independently
    return (StartTime < Now) || (Now < EndTime);
}
else 
{
    // the range is on the same day, both comparisons must be true
    return StartTime < Now && Now < EndTime;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTime nowDate = DateTime.Now;
// set these to today + time from time picker
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(nowDate.Year, nowDate.Month, nowDate.Day,
    selectedStart.Hour, selectedStart.Minute, 0);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(nowDate.Year, nowDate.Month, nowDate.Day, 
    selectedEnd.Hour, selectedEnd.Minute, 0);
bool isBetween = nowDate < endDate && nowDate > startDate;
```

**Update 08-Jun-2016**
Not sure why the downvote was appropriate as this is a working solution. The OP did ask specifically for `DateTime`, however I do recommend using `TimeSpan` instead as per the answer by @Gabe.

Here's a working function as per my answer:

```
public static bool TimeBetween(DateTime check, DateTime start, DateTime end, bool inclusive = true)
{
    var from = new DateTime(check.Year, check.Month, check.Day, 
        start.Hour, start.Minute, start.Second, start.Millisecond);
    var to = new DateTime(check.Year, check.Month, check.Day, 
        end.Hour, end.Minute, end.Second, end.Millisecond);

    if (inclusive)
        return from <= check && to >= check;

    return from < check && to > check;
}
```

Here's a working fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vZCXqv.

Full code:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var start = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 9, 0, 0);
        var end = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 17, 0, 0);

        Console.WriteLine("{0} - Too early",                TimeBetween(new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 08, 59, 59, 999), start, end));
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - On start time exclusive",  TimeBetween(new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 09, 00, 00, 000), start, end, false));
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - On start time inclusive",  TimeBetween(new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 09, 00, 00, 000), start, end));
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - After start time",         TimeBetween(new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 09, 00, 00, 001), start, end));        
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - Before end time",          TimeBetween(new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 16, 59, 59, 999), start, end));
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - On end time inclusive",    TimeBetween(new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 17, 00, 00, 000), start, end));
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - On end time exclusive",    TimeBetween(new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 17, 00, 00, 000), start, end, false));
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - Too late",                 TimeBetween(new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 17, 00, 00, 001), start, end));
    }

    public static bool TimeBetween(DateTime check, DateTime start, DateTime end, bool inclusive = true)
    {
        var from = new DateTime(check.Year, check.Month, check.Day, start.Hour, start.Minute, start.Second, start.Millisecond);
        var to = new DateTime(check.Year, check.Month, check.Day, end.Hour, end.Minute, end.Second, end.Millisecond);

        if (inclusive)
            return from <= check && to >= check;

        return from < check && to > check;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will work regardless of the date right? So if the user sets the time and date this will always work?

Comment: @Niels. Correct. If you store "start=Jan 10th 2012 09:00" the above code will still work for any day.

Comment: Nope, see Gabe's and yhw42's anwers, @Niels.

Answer (score 3):

```
    public static bool isCurrenctDateBetween(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
    {
        DateTime curent = DateTime.Now.Date;
        if (fromDate.CompareTo(toDate) >= 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("From Date shouldn't be grater than To Date", "DateRange",MessageBoxButton.OKCancel, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
        }
        int cd_fd = curent.CompareTo(fromDate);
        int cd_td = curent.CompareTo(toDate);

        if (cd_fd == 0 || cd_td == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (cd_fd >= 1 && cd_td <= -1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update 02-June-2023:**

There is an easier new way to accomplish it using the `TimeOnly` struct type introduced in *.NET 6*.

```
var nowTimeOnly = TimeOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);
var startTimeOnly = new TimeOnly(startTimeHour, startTimeMinute);
var endTimeOnly = new TimeOnly(endTimeHour, endTimeMinute);

if (nowTimeOnly.IsBetween(startTimeOnly, endTimeOnly))
{
}
```

The `IsBetween` method is a [built-in method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timeonly.isbetween?view=net-7.0)

> Determines if a time falls within the range provided.
> Supports both "normal" ranges such as 10:00-12:00, and ranges that span midnight such as 23:00-01:00.

Hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Dupe of [Find if current time falls in a time range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504494/c-sharp-find-if-current-time-falls-in-a-time-range)

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(2009, 12, 9, 10, 0, 0));
DateTime end = new DateTime(2009, 12, 10, 12, 0, 0));
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

if ((now > start) && (now < end))
{
   //match found
}
```

Timespan, again, taken from dupe.

```
TimeSpan start = new TimeSpan(10, 0, 0);
TimeSpan end = new TimeSpan(12, 0, 0);
TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

if ((now > start) && (now < end))
{
   //match found
}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to only use the time part, ignoring the date part

Comment: This still is not okay; see Gabe's and yhw42's answers.

Answer (score 1):

Just do straight comparison.

if(date > startdate && date < enddate)

Comment: How would you get the date? See Gabe's and yhw42's answers.

Answer (score 1):

I use this, so you can pass DateTime directly:

```
        public static bool TimeBetween(DateTime time, DateTime startDateTime, DateTime endDateTime)
    {
        // get TimeSpan
        TimeSpan start = new TimeSpan(startDateTime.Hour, startDateTime.Minute, 0);
        TimeSpan end = new TimeSpan(endDateTime.Hour, endDateTime.Minute, 0);

        // convert datetime to a TimeSpan
        TimeSpan now = time.TimeOfDay;
        // see if start comes before end
        if (start < end)
            return start <= now && now <= end;
        // start is after end, so do the inverse comparison
        return !(end < now && now < start);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner:

```
var isBetweenTwoTimes = TimeOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.UtcNow).IsBetween(new TimeOnly(04, 00), new TimeOnly(10, 00));
```