# ASP.NET Time set function

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer

I have a web page which was implemented in ASP.NET webform.

I have a function in code-behind.

The function is occurred in below condition.

**1. At an interval of user setting.**

For example if user set the interval to 5 min and apply it, the function of the page will be occurred at the 5 min interval.

**2. At the time of user setting.**

For example if user set the date edit control to 17:30:00 and apply it, the function of the page will be occurred at 17:30:00.

User can select the method between 1 or 2.

I already implemented number 1 by asp:Timer control.

I don't know how to implement number 2.

Please give me some advise. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Here is an example of how to implement an alarm clock. It's more or less what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493203/alarm-clock-application-in-net

Comment: implement number 2 the same way as number 1 with timer interval equal to the time between now and 17:30:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to set a timer to go off on the next occurance of a time

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime stopTime = now.Date.AddHours(17).AddMinutes(30); // This is 5:30pm, don't hard code

if (stopTime < now) // If in the past add a day
    stopTime = stopTime.AddDays(1);

TimeSpan timespan = (stopTime - now); // Get the difference between now and the alarm time

// Now set the timer for the difference
timer1.Interval = (int)Math.Round(timespan.TotalMilliseconds); // May want to tweak the rounding
timer1.Enabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented number 2 by asp:Timer control. and it  it will Run at  a  specific time every day
....

```
public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime stopTime = now.Date.AddHours(23).AddMinutes(50); // This is 11:50 pm, don't hard code
            if (stopTime < now) // If in the past add a day
                stopTime = stopTime.AddDays(1);
            TimeSpan timespan = (stopTime - now); // Get the difference between now and the alarm time
            // Now set the timer for the difference
            Timer1.Interval = (int)Math.Round(timespan.TotalMilliseconds); // May want to tweak the rounding
            Timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

    }
    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Your  Logic  To run
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime stopTime = now.Date.AddHours(23).AddMinutes(50); // This is 11:50 pm, don't hard code
        if (stopTime < now) // If in the past add a day
            stopTime = stopTime.AddDays(1);
        TimeSpan timespan = (stopTime - now); // Get the difference between now and the alarm time
        // Now set the timer for the difference
        Timer1.Interval = (int)Math.Round(timespan.TotalMilliseconds); // May want to tweak the rounding
        Timer1.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: just  i want  to add  my  html  but  i m not able  add some  format  reasion of  html