# How to set alarm for a method that is called at a specific time in c#?

Tags: c#

I just want to use system.Thread and console.Beep method to write a program in which my PC beeps when the method is called in a specific time.

Those specific times are saved in an XML file with steam writer. It must check the execution time with those saved times and beeps when they matches.

Comment: I would suggest loading the times, the current time and using DateTime.Subtract to get the Timespan you'll have to wait. You can then use a Timer to fire an event when that much time has passed

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an Alarm Clock, you should use *Threading* &‌ *Timers* namespaces to check the time and handle it.

Follow these links to see how :
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19864/Simple-PC-Alarm-Clock
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3850/Use-a-timer-to-create-a-simple-alarm-application
[Alarm clock application in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493203/alarm-clock-application-in-net)